# When is an Ideal of a PID ring also a vector space?

Tags: ring-theory, vector-spaces

I'm reading David R. Finston and Patrick J. Morandi's book [Abstract Algebra: Structure and Application](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/3319044974) and in section 7.1 page 107 Theorem 7.6 it mentions

> ... if $C$ is an ideal of $\mathbb{Z}_2[x]/(x^n+1)$, 
>   then $C$ is a $\mathbb{Z}_2$ vector subspace of $\mathbb{Z}_2[x]/(x^n+1)$ ...

I wonder, in general, if $C$ is an ideal of a PID ring $R$, when $C$ can be seen as a vector space?

Comment: A vector space over what field? Note that $R=\mathbb Z_2[x]/(x^n+1)$ from the example is a $\mathbb Z_2$-algebra, thus itself a vector space over $\mathbb Z_2$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An ideal $I$ of a ring $R$ with identity is always a unital *module* over a subring $S$  of $R$.  This just follows from the definition of "ideal." $I$ is already an additive group, and the way $S$ acts on it via multiplication already satisfies the module axioms (since it satisfies the ring multiplication axioms.)

In particular, if $S$ is a field, you could call $I$ a vector space (it's just a specific term for a module over a field or division ring.)

Of course, there is no sense in asking "can something be seen as a vector space" without a field being mentioned. You'd have to specify what field you were interested in.

Comment: thank you. Is $S$ generated by some or all of $I$'s generators?

Comment: $S$ doesn't have to have any special relationship to $I$ at all. It just has to be a subring of $R$.  In the case you originally wrote, there is only one nonzero element of $F_2$, and it is $1$, which most definitely *not* in $I$.

Comment: i see i see, now i get it. thx!